Envers Library adding underscore in b/w letters of field/table names like r_e_v_i_n_f_o
I am using dropwizard with maven configuration
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.32.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.32.Final</version>
        </dependency>

with java 17
added @Audited annotations on entity
But envers is trying to search for field/table names with underscore in b/w letters like r_e_v_i_n_f_o, r_e_v , r_e_v_t_y_p_e
I tried following properties also but its not working
  properties:
    charSet: UTF-8
    hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix: _aud
    hibernate.envers.revision_table_name: REVINFO
    hibernate.envers.revision_field_name: REV
    hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name: REVTYPE
    hibernate.physical_naming_strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
    #hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

